# The difference between Manifest.xml and config.xml for phonegap build apps

Tags: android, jquery, ios, xml, cordova

I am working on an android app with Phonegap and Jquery Mobile which I will compile with `build.phonegap.com`.

I first want to know the difference between `Manifest.xml` and `config.xml` files, and also whether it is required to add androidManifest.xml when i am uploading the files to `build.phonegap.com`.

Secondly i will like to know if there will a device problem assuming i add three different Manifest.xml for three difference devices eg, `android, ios and blackberry` when i upload the files to phonegap build.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First Answer:  Diff between manifest.xm and config.xml files .... now manifest is where u declare stuff like

1> Package
2>version 
3> install location and many more btw i just finish one of my phongap and there is not config in my files though ...

second question .. i dont know about that david ... you can probly go to google !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `manifest.xml` is using only for your android application. It defines permissions, services, broadcastresivers ,activities and intents. This file will be using by `JVM` to register your application on device.
`Config.xml` is using for `cordova` library, to define all plugins(interfaces between js and jsvs layer).

Comment: thank you, i know i have to place the config.xml in the document root folder where my index.html is, however i am pretty confuse of where to place the androidManifest.xml. i am developing the app with dreamweaver and later deploy to build.phonegap.com for compilation

Comment: i too have a same question and one more doubt that where and how to place the plugin written by me in the build